# If I download a free font and upload it for download on my server is that illegal

Tags: fonts, legal

I use to download fonts from places like DaFont and use them on my computer and designs. I also use to upload these free for download fonts onto my server and have them linked to be able to be downloaded by anyone on my website.

I was informed that someone I know got a letter threatening to be sued if the links weren't removed. I figured they probably used a font that was not free for download.

My question is, is that if they are free to download from multiple sites is it illegal to for me to have them for download on my site. Right now I have them linked to the sites I found them on but that is a true hassle and I'm looking to not do that anymore.

Comment: I do not understand how it can be more of a hassle to link to a site than to a file.

Comment: It is not an immediate issue, but it introduces maintenance load, because you have to watch for broken links.

Answer (score 7):

Free for download doesn't necessarily mean free for redistribution. The fonts at DaFont have different licences, and you'd better check for each font you download. Some have quite restrictive licences, and some are even [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain) or [Creative Commons - Attribution](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)

Check [this one](http://www.dafont.com/plicata.font) for example. To the right, just above the Download button, it says *Free for personal use*. This hints strongly at what you're allowed to do. Every font I've ever downloaded from DaFont also had a readme file explaining the exact terms applying to the font.